# Exposure triangle

Tags: exposure

If I set my f-stop to f1.8 and my shutter speed to 1/125th of a second and my ISO is maxed at 6400, yet my image is coming out dark. What is the problem and what can I do? Why?

Comment: Did you shoot in an unlit cellar or on a glacier under a blue sky? Those values are quite meaningless without knowing the scene.

Comment: Why are you unwilling to use a shutter speed longer than 1/125 sec? Are you trying to freeze some kind of motion, or just trying to avoid camera shake? Have you considered using a tripod?

Comment: Post an example, it is impossible to guess what are you doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "exposure triangle"?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)

Comment: We need more information to pinpoint what your issue could be. Are you sure you took off the lens cap? What camera are you using? Are you using a pinhole lens? What lens are you using? Does your camera have a built-in ND filter that's been activated? What are you shooting? When you say "coming out dark" is it completely black? Or underexposed? etc. etc.  An example image would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

If your image is coming out dark you need to increase the exposure. You can do this in 3 ways:

1. Allow more light to enter the lens - You state that your aperture is set to f1.8, I will assume that this is the maximum aperture, so we will move on.
2. Record more of the light hitting the sensor - You state that you are already at the highest ISO setting for your camera, again we will move on.
3. Increase the time the sensor is exposed to light - Increasing the shutter speed will allow for more light to hit the sensor, resulting in a brighter image.

The other option is to add more light to the scene, for example by using flash, but this would be out of the scope of a question about "Exposure triangle".

Answer (score 2):

> What is the problem and what can I do?

Whenever you have too dark image:

- decrease F number
- increase exposure time
- increase your ISO number
- use flash

or use automatic exposure mode (A, P, S or auto) instead.

If you cannot record image of well lit scene in automatic exposure mode or camera sets too unusual settings compared to other cameras you might have a problem with your equipment. Let me know if it is the case.